# Datasnap Server and TFDConnection place

Tags: database, delphi, connection, structure, datasnap

Planning my datasnap server application. Where should I place the connection to the database?

Create a TDatamodule "MainConn" with only the connection (and necessary drivers) and access from my other datamodule (dm1, dm2 dm..), to this MainConn.connection1.

Another option would be to place TFDConnection in the datamodule where TDSServer resides next to all the TDSServerclass.

And finally, each DM with its own TFDConnection (very unlikely)

What would be the right option?

I look forward to your comments

Comment: Look at what the Datasnap server wizard gives you. It is important to understand that a Datasnap server creates an instance of the datamodule for each incoming connection to the Datasnap server, so that you don't have to write threaded code.

Comment: Then the last option is the right one. Each DM must contain a TFDConnection. But in this way the number of connections to the DB is huge and uncontrollable.

Comment: Each DM can have as many functions as you need. How huge is your system going to be?